# Merge list for 2d list, its separating correctly but when it comes back all together it is wrong,

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

Here is my code, the code is usual merge sort but with my print statements showing each step, the only issue I have is when it comes back all together there are duplicate values and stuff of that matter

```
def mergeSort(list):
    if len(list) > 1:
        mid = len(list) // 2 
        left = list[:mid]
        right = list[mid:]
        
        print("left:\n"+str(left).replace("],","]\n")) 
        print("right:\n"+str(right).replace("],","]\n")) 
        print("")
            
        #recursion
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)
        
        i = j = k = 0
        
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i][0] < right[j][0]:
                list[k].append(left[i][0])
                i += 1
            else:
                list[k].append(right[j][0])
                j += 1
            k += 1

        while i < len(left):
            list[k].append(left[i][0])
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(right):
            list[k].append(right[j][0])
            j += 1
            k += 1
```

This is the output

```
left:
[['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00']
 ['20', 'Mark', 'Z.', '$123.00']
 ['18', 'Susan', 'K.', '$0.00']]
right:
[['25', 'Paul', 'A.', '$0.00']
 ['44', 'Elvis', 'P.', '$4,000.00']
 ['8', 'Lucas', 'L.', '$5.00']]

left:
[['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00']]
right:
[['20', 'Mark', 'Z.', '$123.00']
 ['18', 'Susan', 'K.', '$0.00']]

left:
[['20', 'Mark', 'Z.', '$123.00']]
right:
[['18', 'Susan', 'K.', '$0.00']]

left:
[['25', 'Paul', 'A.', '$0.00']]
right:
[['44', 'Elvis', 'P.', '$4,000.00']
 ['8', 'Lucas', 'L.', '$5.00']]

left:
[['44', 'Elvis', 'P.', '$4,000.00']]
right:
[['8', 'Lucas', 'L.', '$5.00']]

[['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00', '20', '21']
 ['20', 'Mark', 'Z.', '$123.00', '18', '18', '20']
 ['18', 'Susan', 'K.', '$0.00', '20', '21', '18']
 ['25', 'Paul', 'A.', '$0.00', '25', '25']
 ['44', 'Elvis', 'P.', '$4,000.00', '44', '44', '44']
 ['8', 'Lucas', 'L.', '$5.00', '8', '8', '8']]
```

I was able to merge sort if it was just an array with the same "first column values" and thats how I know it is separating correctly. I just cannot see where I went wrong with my function, maybe im just blind.

Comment: Never **ever** call a variable `list` in python. This name is already used for the class `list`.

Comment: The line `list[k].append(left[i][0])` is wrong, I think. It should be simply `list[k] = left[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

I found three mistakes in your code.

### Never ever call a variable `list` in python

Find another name for the argument of your function. `list` is already the name of the class that handles everything related to lists in python. Giving this name to another object leads to unforeseen trouble. Instead, call your variable `l`, or `ll`, or `myList`, or whatever other name you can think of.

### You are comparing strings instead of numbers

By default, strings are compared according to lexicographical order. Thus, `'2' > '18'`, because `'2'` begins with the character `'2'` whereas `'18'` begins with the character `'1'`. This is most likely not what you want. You can either modify your list before sorting to replace those strings with numbers; or you can replace your test `if left[i][0] < right[j][0]:` with `if int(left[i][0]) < int(right[j][0]):`

### Your merge function is appending the wrong things at the wrong places

Let me illustrate the effect of the line `list[k].append(left[i][0])` using python's interactive interpreter:

```py
>>> left = [['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00'],['20', 'Mark', 'Z.', '$123.00'],['18', 'Susan', 'K.', '$0.00']]
>>> myList = [['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00'],['20', 'Mark', 'Z.', '$123.00'],['18', 'Susan', 'K.', '$0.00'],['25', 'Paul', 'A.', '$0.00'],['44', 'Elvis', 'P.', '$4,000.00'],['8', 'Lucas', 'L.', '$5.00']]
>>> i = 0
>>> k = 0
>>> myList[k].append(left[i][0])
>>> myList
[['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00', '21'],
 ['20', 'Mark', 'Z.', '$123.00'],
 ['18', 'Susan', 'K.', '$0.00'],
 ['25', 'Paul', 'A.', '$0.00'],
 ['44', 'Elvis', 'P.', '$4,000.00'],
 ['8', 'Lucas', 'L.', '$5.00']]
```

**What happened?** `myList[k]` is an element of `myList`: since `myList` is a list of lists, in this case it's the list corresponding to John. `left[i]` is the first element of `left`; since `left` is a list of lists, in this case it's the list corresponding to John. Finally, `left[i][0]` is the first element of John's list, which is the string `'21'`. So you are appending the element `'21'` to the list `['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00']`, and this results in John's list in `myList` becoming `['21', 'John', 'S.', '$100.00', '21']`.

**How to fix it?** Simply write `myList[k] = left[i]` instead. This will replace the kth element of `myList` with the ith element of `left`, which is what you want.

Comment: wow thanks for the help and explanation I was able to fix my program, It was very late when I was programming this so many things went over my head. If I were able to upvote I would !